# Polymorphic Association lookup class name with Namespaced Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Project` model.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, as: :target # polymorphic
end
```

I have also applied the namespacing pattern to extend `Project`, for admins to manipulate:

```
class Admin::Project < Project
  def action_for_admin; end
end
```

This is mainly for the Admin controllers.

However since `Project` has many foos, which is a polymorphic association. An `Admin::Project` can't find the association properly.

Calling `Admin::Project.first.foos` gives this SQL:

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."target_id" = $1 AND "foos"."target_type" = $2  [["target_id", 1], ["target_type", "Foo::Project"]]
```

The `target_type` searches for `Admin::Project`, but it actually contains `"Project"`

Is there a way for `Admin::Project` and `Project` to work with polymorphic association together?

Comment: What rails version are you using? It works for me in 5.2. Did you check https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#1010-Polymorphic-has-many-within-inherited-class-gotcha

Comment: @AbM I am on 5.0.7. Thanks for mentioning that reference!